# Can't download a file in the same LAN using BitTorrent

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

Context:

Computer 1:

- ThinkPad
- Windows 7
- Latest version of uTorrent
- Contains the one and only copy of a big file

Computer 2:

- Desktop computer
- Windows 7
- Latest version of uTorrent

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Make a new torrent on the ThinkPad with the big file.
2. Copy and paste the magnet URL into the desktop.

Expected Result:

A speedy download.

Actual Result:

Nothing.

Local Peer Discovery is enabled on both computers.

Comment: Are you're firewalls in the way?  Does uTorrent work as expected otherwise (ie: can download torrent found on a tracker) on both computers?  Can they communicate otherwise (ping, etc.)?  How long did you wait before giving up on the transfer to start?

Comment: You expect the transfer from one computer to the other to be faster via bottorrent rather than a direct file transfer?  Are both clients using the same port?

Comment: I don't expect it to be faster but I expect it to work.

Comment: As for ports, I'm not sure what you mean. uTorrent automatically handles that with UPnP.

Comment: uTorrent works as expected otherwise. The two computers can see each other as I'm able to Remote Desktop into the desktop from the ThinkPad.